# how to use the same image of 160ppi and 1280X800 ressolution device in 800X1280 and 214ppi device

Tags: android

I have a `app` which i developed for `10.1 inch` tab which has `resolution` `1280x800` and having `Density 160ppi`,so when i am running the same app on a `7inch tab` with has `resolution of 800X1280` and having `density 214ppi` in that the UI of the app is looking kinda weird they are looking bigger as compare to `10inch` tab. so what step should i follow to resolve this issue.**Note**: The Images that i am using in my App is initially designed `1280X800 and 160ppi density.`

Answer (score 1):

```
1280 x 800 160ppi is MDPI devices

800 x 1280 214PPi us TVDPI devices
```

//you need to supply different density Images like

MDPI and HDPI images

TVDPI devices will pick from HDPI image and auto scale them

//you can also supply different `drawable` for `large` and `xlarge` drawables.

Comment: how you did? what you did?

Comment: i put all the images i am using as background in my project in hdpi folder but all are not displaying properly.

Comment: copying assets from MDPI to HDPI wont work. need to create separate assets for different densities.

Comment: and one more question i have also design my layout from 10.1 tab do i need to design it again for 7 inch and do i need to put it into there folder accordingly.

Comment: no need for separate assests for 10' and 7' its enough. Only you need a different background in drawable-large folder.